# Why does Azure Repos sometimes shows my check-in(s) as Author = '--get.all'?

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-repos

Azure sometimes shows my check-in(s) as Author = '--get.all' as apposed to my name.

From Visual Studio > make changes to a branch > commit changes > Open VS's Git Repo > sync button (pull & push).
Then I got to Azure URL > browse changes where I just commited. In some cases my name shows as Author. In some cases '--get.all' shows as author.

[image]

Comment: Probably a messed up git config file in either a repo or your user profile. Try running `get config --list` to see where the username has been defined. You may have to search your hard drive in case you have more than 1 git installation, since each has its own system level config.

Comment: If.you have multiple local clones of the same repo, then the value may also be stored in a specific repos local config.

Comment: >get config --list   -->


user.name=--get.all

Comment: That's causing your name to be not what you want. You can unset it with `git config --unset-all user.name` and then set it again `git config --add user.name="Bill XXX"`

Answer (score 1):

Probably a messed up git config file in either a repo or your user profile. Try running get config --list to see where the username has been defined. You may have to search your hard drive in case you have more than 1 git installation, since each has its own system level config.

If you have multiple local clones of the same repo, then the value may also be stored in a specific repos local config.

You're seeing:

```
>get config --list
user.name=--get.all
```

That's causing your name to be not what you want. You can unset it with `git config --unset-all user.name` and then set it again `git config --add user.name="Bill XXX" --global`.

```
git config --unset-all user.name
git config --add user.name="Bill XXX" --global
```

Comment: Fixing the commits with the wrong username is a bit more work. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61368365/736079